# Recursive equations with matrices, and a question about determinants in relation to power of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If we have the matrix equation $AX^{(i)} = X^{(i+1)}$ where $A$ is a constant matrix, this is what we'd call a recursive function; in matrix form.

Moreover, if $X^{(i+1)} = X^{(i)}$, i.e. $AX = X$ our matrix $X$ represents an equilibrium state for our system.

---

With the last equation, multiplying by the inverse of $X$, assuming $X$ is inversible, we get the following: $A = I$. This is what's bothering me.

- Say I had already defined $A\not=I$ , and had found the equilibrium state for $X$, whatever that is, doesn't this contradict the definition above?

---

And another question, which I have also wondered about some:

- If we define the matrix $A$ with the property $A^2 = A$, which determinant can $A$ have?

Here I also tried multiplying by the inverse of $A$, and got that $A = I$. Hence, $\det A = 1$. Is this proof enough? Does this prove that any matrix $B^2=B \implies B = I$?

*I have a suspicion that my reasoning is off because the proof above only shows for when $\det A\not=0$, i.e. $A$ **is** invertible.*

Comment: For your first question: perhaps the equilibrium state of any nontrivial recursive function must not be an invertible matrix?
For your second question: Remember that $det(A^2) = det(AA) = det(A)det(A) = det(A)^2$. We thus see in this case that $det(A) = det(A)^2$. What numbers $x$ are such that $x^2 = x$?

Comment: Actually, this reminded me of one important thing. Determinants are only defined for square matrices. How could I forget that.. I think at least now I will remember this.

Comment: Please see my edit for your second question.

Comment: @Bib Thank you for your help. And making use of the product rule for determinants sure makes it clear that $B^2 = B \iff B = I$.

Comment: That isn't true though! There is another number that gives itself when squared.

Comment: $B^2=B\iff B\,$ is the matrix of a (parallel) projection onto a subspace.